# Check if script run as standalone or from django interface

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface

ALL,

I developed a script that was running from the CLI. The script purpose is to load the data from the csv file and push it into the mySQL.
Now, the script is modified in order to run from Django, so that user click a button in the browser called "Browse...", select the csv file and then the file will be read and the data pushed to mySQL with my script.

Now my problem is that for the database there is a table which should contain 2 fields: one is the local filename, the other - a filename on the user machine for the web interface (django).

And so my question is simple: is it possible to find out whether I start the script from the CLI or from the Django web application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, if the current script is being run as the main program, the special python variable `__name__` will be set to the string `"__main__"`.

Therefore, to detect if the script is being run straight from the command line e.g `python my_script.py`, just use an `if` statement such as

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_stuff()
```